# Specify tab order for SAP UI5 screen fields, buttons, and other controls

Tags: tabs, sapui5, tab-ordering

When we write pure HTML code, we loop through input controls on the screen using:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Controlling TAB Order</title>
  </head> 
<body>
  <form>
    Field 1 (first tab selection):
    <input type="text" name="field1" tabindex=1 /><br />
    Field 2 (third tab selection):
    <input type="text" name="field2" tabindex=3 /><br /> 
    Field 3 (second tab selection):
    <input type="text" name="field3" tabindex=2 /><br />
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: how would we achieve the same in a UI5 application since we do not have attributes for input controls that allow us to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the HTML attributes using jQuery .attr() function after the HTML of the form is rendered during the afterRendering event. [See documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f1b3856f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)